# How to generate dbContext and entities without visual studio for Postgres and MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, postgresql, edmgen

I need to generate dbContext and entities without visual studio for Postgres and MSSQL.

I tried to use edmgen.exe, but it's create ObjectContext, not DbContext. And it's not work with Postgres.

How I can do it?

Comment: When you've generated them, what will you do with them without Visual Studio?

Comment: I provide my application to integration departament, they should generate items and dbcontext and load to my application without recompilation, My application will use entities via reflection